# Add column while change items labels and levels

Tags: r

I want to add a column to my df, meanwhile I want to change labels and levels, I tried this:

```
df <- data.frame(Col1 = c(1:9), Col2 = c(2:10), Col3 = c(3:11))
rownames(df)<-c("a1","a2", "a3", "b1","b2", "b3", "c1","c2", "c3")

df<-cbind(ID = factor(rownames(df),labels=c("a1"="Ctr","a2"="Ctr","a3"="Ctr",
                                                    "b1"="P","b2"="P","b3"="P",
                                                    "c1"="M","c2"="M","c3"="M"), 
                                   levels=c("Ctr", "P", "M")), df)
```

Output should be:

```
   ID Col1 Col2 Col3
a1 Ctr    1    2    3
a2 Ctr    2    3    4
a3 Ctr    3    4    5
b1   P    4    5    6
b2   P    5    6    7
b3   P    6    7    8
c1   M    7    8    9
c2   M    8    9   10
c3   M    9   10   11
```

Comment: Would `df$ID <- rep(c("Ctr", "P", "M"), each = 3)` will work for you?

Comment: Rows might be mixed and I might not know how many items each group contains, also I want change levels  while I rename the items. Also the ID column should come first

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to remove the numbers from the row names (`v1`), create a named vector with the `uniques` value of 'v1', use that to match the values in 'v1' and create a new column 'ID'

```
v1 <- sub("\\d+", "", rownames(df))
transform(df, ID= setNames(c("Ctr", "P", "M"), unique(v1))[v1])[c(4, 1:3)]
#    ID Col1 Col2 Col3
#a1 Ctr    1    2    3
#a2 Ctr    2    3    4
#a3 Ctr    3    4    5
#b1   P    4    5    6
#b2   P    5    6    7
#b3   P    6    7    8
#c1   M    7    8    9
#c2   M    8    9   10
#c3   M    9   10   11
```

---

Or other option is `factor`

```
factor(sub("\\d+", "", rownames(df)), labels = c("Ctr", "P", "M"))
#[1] Ctr Ctr Ctr P   P   P   M   M   M
```

---

Or another option is `dplyr/tibble`.  We create the 'ID' column from the row names (`rownames_to_column` from `tibble`), `mutate` the 'ID' to new values using `case_when`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)
rownames_to_column(df, var="ID")  %>% 
           mutate(ID = case_when(.$ID %in% c("a1", "a2", "a3") ~ "Ctr", 
                                 .$ID %in% c("b1", "b2", "b3") ~ "P", 
                                  TRUE ~ "M"))
#   ID Col1 Col2 Col3
#1 Ctr    1    2    3
#2 Ctr    2    3    4
#3 Ctr    3    4    5
#4   P    4    5    6
#5   P    5    6    7
#6   P    6    7    8
#7   M    7    8    9
#8   M    8    9   10
#9   M    9   10   11
```

Comment: Hi the last option works fine; but I don't understand why the first option returns `Error in setNames(c("Ctr", "P", "M"), unique(v1)) : 
  'names' attribute [4] must be the same length as the vector [3]`

Comment: @Al14  I was using your example and it worked for me. Is the error on your original dataset?  In that case, check for any NA or blanks.

Comment: But the last option did not fix the levels order

Comment: @Al14  It is not clear what you meant by fixing the order.  I created a `character` in the last option, if you need to convert to `factor`, then add at the end  `%>% mutate(ID = factor(ID, levels =  c("Ctr", "P", "M")))`.  But, if you have rownames other than 'a', 'b' and 'c', then it needs to be taken into account

Comment: I want also to define levels when I mutate the IDs, can this be done inside`rownames_to_column(df, var="ID")  %>% 
           mutate(ID = case_when(.$ID %in% c("a1", "a2", "a3") ~ "Ctr", 
                                 .$ID %in% c("b1", "b2", "b3") ~ "P", 
                                  TRUE ~ "M"))`

Answer (score 0):

you can use `ifelse()` in combination with `grepl()` to create the `ID` column in a generic way.

```
idCol <- rownames(df)
idCol <- ifelse(grepl("a", idCol), "Ctr", 
                ifelse(grepl("b", idCol), "P", "M"))
idCol
# [1] "Ctr" "Ctr" "Ctr" "P"   "P"   "P"   "M"   "M"   "M"  

df$ID <- as.factor(idCol)
df
#    Col1 Col2 Col3  ID
# a1    1    2    3 Ctr
# a2    2    3    4 Ctr
# a3    3    4    5 Ctr
# b1    4    5    6   P
# b2    5    6    7   P
# b3    6    7    8   P
# c1    7    8    9   M
# c2    8    9   10   M
# c3    9   10   11   M
```